# How to read JSON data with Java

Tags: java, json

Am having a problem reading/parsing the following JSON string in Java.

Code:

```
try{
  json = new JSONObject(result);
//json now looks like this :-
// {'header': '[{"doc_no": "DN00001","stage":"P"}]','section':'[{"upper":100,"lower":1]'}
  if (json != null){
     // this line is throwing an exception!!
     JSONObject header =  new JSONObject("header");
   }catch(JSONException e){
    // Error Message
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
JSONArray  header = json.getJSONArray("header");
```

but still throwing some exception.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think you need to obtain the `header` field from the variable `json`. Creating new JSONObject looks weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here dude take this code. Fix your JSON string if you wanted to get JSONObject out of it

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
    String result = "{'header': '[{\"doc_no\": \"DN00001\",\"stage\":\"P\"}]','section':'[{\"upper\":100,\"lower\":1]'}";
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
    // json now looks like this :-
    //
    if (json != null) {
        String header = json.getString("header");
        System.out.println(header);
    }

}
```

So what's wrong with you? Couple of things:

1. Your JSON string is all illegal. Thanks to parsers to bear with you. It should be

   ```
   {
     "header": [{"doc_no": "DN00001","stage":"P"}],
     "section":[{"upper":100,"lower":1]
   }
   ```
2. It wont solve your problem alone. Since you wanted to get `JSONObject` but you provided a `JSONArray` (why did you do that?). So remove those square brackets.
3. Still not happy. You see you are trying to create a new `JSONObject` by doing (obviously) `new JSONObject("header")` using a string taht is not a JSON. 9And expecting it not to throw error? How cruel.) Plus you wanted to `get` not `set`. So use `json.getXXX("header")` where XXX can be `String`, `JSONObject` or `JSONArray` and many more.

Comment: Great!, but if you read my question i also attempted to getJSONArray("header") with no luck, good pointers though ...

Comment: @gath dude, you need to fix your JSON string like #1. Skip #2 if you want `JSONArray`. In #3, use `json.getJSONArray("header");`.

Comment: Though everyone gave a pointer to the right direction i.e the json string was not formatted correctly, i'll pick this answer for its extensive explanation. Thanks all, my server(in python) was not formatting the json correctly, i have modified it and now all keys in the json have double quotes {"header":[{"doc_no":"DN00001"}]}.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a valid JSON file.

```
'header': '[{"doc_no": "DN00001","stage":"P"}]'
```

Array can't be surrounded with `'`
String should be surrounded with `"` instead of `'`

Read http://json.org/ about JSON syntax.

Comment: Why is it not a valid JSON. It's a valid JSON with key 'header' and value as *string* [{"doc_no": "DN00001","stage":"P"}], It's not strictly valid but most of the parsers would work.

Comment: "not strictly valid" means it's not valid - some parsers might have less enforcement

Comment: Then it should be surrounded with `"` and not `'`.

Comment: @TS -- I am not going down into perfectness... the code OP posted is wrong. This answer does not adresses the fact that `JSONObject("header")` is trying to create a `JSON` object from String "header". You can parse single quoted JSON String with JSONObject.

Comment: @Nishant gath wrote that he tried `json.getJSONArray("header")` which should work in this case.

Comment: @Nishant I voted for it, but it still doesn't resolve problem with `json.getJSONArray("header")`.

Comment: How do i make it a valid json object?

Comment: @pawelzieba I have updated the answer. I wont spoon feed. The OP code is in bad shape. I tried to clarify the situation

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject header =  new JSONObject("header");
```

Did you mean to get the "header" field from your existing object?

```
JSONObject header =  json.getJSONObject("header");
```

But judging from your comment

```
// {'header': '[{"doc_no": "DN00001","stage":"P"}]','section':'[{"upper":100,"lower":1]'}
```

you intend "header" to be an array (not an object), but the data has it as a String (that looks like an array), so you probably need to fix the JSON as well as the Java code.

Answer (score 0):

`JSONObject header =  new JSONObject("header");`

don't you mean to **get** the header from `json`, not create a  new `JSONObject`?

as in

`JSONObject header = json.get("header");`